# Swift 4 - Button over Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I am trying to position a custom button over one of the item of my Tab bar.

```
func setupMiddleButton() {

    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarItemSize.width, height: self.tabBar.frame.size.height))
    var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
    menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame

    menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.view.addSubview(menuButton)


    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

My issue is that with the previous code the button is not perfectly over the bar item (see picture):
[image]

Any suggestion? I really don't know how else to try.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I notice that this screenshot is of an iPhone X Simulator, which has a different layout at the bottom of the screen.
Your code works well on any other iPhone. In iOS 11 they introduced what's called the "Safe area". When you calculate the size and origin for your button, you will have to take that into account.

When you calculate the `origin.y` for your buttonFrame, you have to subtract the height for the safe-area at the bottom, like this:

```
menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

This won't solve your problem though, as your code probably runs in `viewDidLoad`, which happens before the view knows it's supposed be displayed on an iPhone X with a safe area.

You can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for this, and set the correct frame for your button each time that is called.

This will fix your issue:

```
class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMiddleButton()
    }
    func setupMiddleButton() {
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
        let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
        menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarItemSize.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
        menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
        menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(menuButton)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        menuButton.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButton.frame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
}
```

[image: Fixed]

I know it's tempting to simply call `setupMiddleButton` from inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but do not do that. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should not be used to create buttons etc., it should only be used to move them accordingly to the rest of the view. You might want to set the entire frame of `menuButton` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` rather than only the `origin.y` like I did, especially if you need to support rotation/landscape-mode. In this very simple example, updating `origin.y` is enough.

Comment: I was looking around and i've just noticed the problem was the extra space for the iPhone X..however i wouldn't know how to solve this... so Thank you you just saved me a lot of time... your solution fixed the problem 100%! Now it works perfectly! Thx!